# I have to find two smallest numbers without arrays

Tags: c, do-while

So basicly I have this assignement in C, I have to input numbers until I enter 0, and after I enter 0 I have to print 1st and 2nd min number from all that numbers and I can't use arrays. I get that I have to use do-while loop for input but I can't figure out how to find two smallest from all of them. I think that thing can be done with if loops but don't know how to make it as I have only one variable to enter numbers into it (int a). And in input I have error when I enter 0 I'm able to enter one more number before program quits.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main() {

        int a;

        do {
            printf("Enter numbers: ");
            scanf("%d\n", &a);
        //what to do here
        }while(a != 0);
```

Comment: can't be done unless you're allowed to add more variables

Comment: You need other 2 variables to do what you want.

Comment: _if loops_....does not make any sense...

Comment: You can use them later in IF loop or something like that but for inputing numbers you have to use only one because you don't have specific limit of how much numbers you can enter, you only have instruction to stop entering numbers when you enter 0...

Comment: `scanf("%d\n", &a);` ---> `scanf("%d", &a);`... this is why you must input always a number after 0, or after each value...

Comment: it worked, tnx...

Comment: "as I have only one variable to enter numbers into it" Try sticking both your feet into one of your shoes. If you have limited success in that, it might be a good idea to question if the specification actually makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add 2 variables to hold the smallest values detected so far. Like

```
int smallest = INT_MAX;
int second_smallest = INT_MAX;
```

Then in the loop you need to test if the new input value is smaller than the values stored so far. Something like:

```
if (a <= smallest)
{
    second_smallest = smallest;
    smallest = a;
}
else if (a < second_smallest)
{
    second_smallest = a;
}
```

Comment: what this INT_MAX means, is that like a fixed value?

Comment: Quite identical solutions ;) BTW why `<=` ?? I think OP wants the smallest-s of the whole set, repeated numbers can be ignored, I guess.

Comment: I believe it has to be `<`only because if you type 2 times the same number, it will become smallest and second_smallest which is wrong I guess.

Comment: @LPs Well, I assumed OP wanted to catch repeated numbers. Anyway, it doesn't matters whether the first if uses `<=` or `<`. Repeated numbers will be accepted in both cases. If repeated numbers is to be avoided both the first and the second `if` must be changed.

Comment: @SvenB - For INT_MAX see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/limits.h

Comment: @tilz0R - Changing `<=` to `<` does **not** avoid repeated smallest number. See my comment to LPs above.

Comment: I don't understand. If I send 10, 10 in sequence, then `second_smallest = something; smallest = 10` and in next loop I enter this loop again and I have `second_smallest = 10, smallest = 10` So this is not ok?

Comment: @tilz0R - It is not clear whether OP wants repeated numbers or not. My code allows repeated numbers. If you change `<=` to `<` it will **still accept` repeated numbers. It takes more than that to avoid repeated numbers.

Comment: No, how can it accept. Imagine that `smallest = 10` and `previous_smallest = 11`: Sequence is `11, 10, 10`. When second `10` arrives, first `if`won't be executed.

Comment: @tilz0R - You write: `When second 10 arrives, first ifwon't be executed` That is correct. But the **second `if` will execute** and then you'll have `10` for both `smallest` and `second_smallest`

Comment: What about this modification: change `else if (a < second_smallest)` to `else if (a != smallest && a < second_smallest)` and remove `=`in first if.

Comment: @tilz0R - With that update then repeated numbers are avoided. But my point was only that changing `<=` to `<` didn't.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two variables to do what you need

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{

    int a = INT_MAX;
    int min_1 = INT_MAX;
    int min_2 = INT_MAX;

    int valid;

    do
    {
        if (a < min_1)
        {
            min_2 = min_1;
            min_1 = a;

        }
        else if (a < min_2)
        {
            min_2 = a;
        }

        printf("Enter numbers: ");
        valid = scanf("%d", &a);
    }
    while ((a != 0) && (valid == 1));

    if (valid == 1)
    {
        printf("Minimum numbers entered are: %d %d\n", min_1, min_2);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in data input\n");
    }
}
```

So:

1. use `limits.h` defines to init min variables to the highest value for `int` type `INT_MAX`.
2. for each loop you must test if entered number is a minimum
3. you must check that user input  is valid: check `scanf` return value.
4. remove `\n` in the format string of `scanf`.

Comment: yep, Quite identical solutions ;) Also I'll +1 you for including stuff like `limits.h` and improved `scanf` handling